# Инпутов с одинаковым именем как их принять и сохранить?

Tags: php, массивы, mysqli, codeigniter

Есть форма - внутри 2 инпута и 1 select.и внизу кнопка плюс. При нажатии на кнопку через append добавляются эти же инпуты и select. Но при отправке не пойму как сохранить в бд.Использую php.Codeigniter 3. Вопрос как их принять и сохранить?

```
                <div class="hotel form-group">
                <label for="sel1">Отели</label>
                <input required type="text" name="hotel_name[]" class="form- 
                 control" placeholder="Название отеля">
                <input required type="text" name="hotel_price[]" 
                class="form-control" placeholder="Цена отеля>
                <select required class="form-control" name="hotel_star[]" 
                 id="sel1">
                    <option value="">Уровень отеля(звездочки)</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                </select>
               </div>
```

Comment: На стороне сервера: $this->input->post('name') или $this->input->get('name')

Comment: @SergeyArchipov не сохраняются так как несколько inputov с одним name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На стороне клиента генерируете инпуты, где название = массив. Т.е. так:

```
<input type="text" name="array[]">
```

Где `array` = название переменной.

На сервере данные придут в `$this->input->post("array", TRUE)` в виде массива, которые потом можно будет перебрать через `foreach`, т.е. для вставки в БД:

```
foreach ($this->input->post("array", TRUE) as $item) 
{
  //вставляем данные в БД, в $item содержится каждый инпут.
}
```

Хочу сразу заметить одну деталь. Если через `append` Вы вставляете несколько input'ов (к примеру, если нужно создать товары, у которых должны быть название и цена), то в обязательном порядке эти инпуты необходимо нумеровать. Т.е. Вам нужно создать переменную, которая будет инкрементиться, когда будет добавлен новый блок. Для примера, на банальном jQuery:

```
var i = 0;
var container = $('.items-container');
$('.add-item').click(function(){
  var nameInput = $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'text',
    name: 'product[ + i + ][name]'
  });
  var priceInput = $('<input>').attr({
    type: 'text',
    name: 'product[ + i + ][price]'
  });
  container.append(nameInput).append(priceInput);
  i++;
});
```

Таким образом, на выходе мы получим 2 инпута, но они будут связаны между собой одним индексом в массиве:

```
<input type="text" name="product[0][name]">
<input type="text" name="product[0][price]">
```

Comment: В `CI` надо использовать `$this->input->post("array", TRUE)` - такую конструкцию для получения `POST`

Comment: @Manitikyl пока писал, забыл, что вопрос про CI :) Сейчас исправлю.

Comment: плюсанул за старания, а вообще вопрос не понятный. Нужно просить примеры кода, чтобы видеть что там не так.

Comment: @Manitikyl автор не до конца понимает, как работать с массивами в input'ах. Хоть это и говорит о том, что знания для CI/любого фреймворка слишком малы, на его вопрос все-таки я ответил

Comment: @Alexxosipov вроде понятно, а то долго мучался.

Comment: @Alexxosipov у меня получается 3 инпута, когда в бд буду сохранят 3 foreach будет. Правильно?

Comment: @Улан вот если у вас 3 инпута, то эти инпуты и нужно писать в вопрос. Поправьте вопрос, чтобы он был полезен не только вам, но и участникам сообщества.

Comment: @Alexxosipov поправил